# Why is Vuejs not updating elements in time?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am currently faced with a situation where I add options to a select element via vuejs when the @change of that specific element is called.

The problem is that the new option is not 'registered' until I leave the function.

I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/bz8361Lp/

In this demo, if a option in the select element is selected, a new option is added to the select. The console is still printing the old number of entries.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: {
      data: ["test", "hallo", "bye"]
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      console.log("test")
      this.data.push("hello")
      const element = document.getElementById("select")
      console.log(element.options.length)
    }
  }
})
```

I am looking for some guidance on how I can avoid this problem, what I am doing wrong and what a best practice could be.

Thanks.

Comment: Please look at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Vue.js updates DOM not immediately but on the next event loop processing.
You can read about this in detail [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue)

You can check this by using `nextTick`:

```
onChange(event) {
      console.log("test")
      this.data.push("hello")
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        const element = document.getElementById("select")
        console.log(element.options.length)
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

need to wait for the dom to render and then evaluate. You can find more information about what the function does '' `this.$nextTick()`

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: {
      data: ["test", "hallo", "bye"]
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      console.log("test")
      this.data.push("hello")
      
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        const element = document.getElementById("select")
        console.log(element.options.length)
      })
    }
  }
})
```